# How can I correct this program to prevent it from throwing java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

So this is the program I wrote for School:

```
import java.io.*;
public class p35{
public static void main()throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    System.out.println("Enter c for circle,r for rectangle and t for triangle");

    char a = (char)br.read();
    switch(a)
    {
        case 'c': System.out.println("Enter radius");
                  String r = br.readLine();
                  int rad = Integer.parseInt(r);
                  System.out.println("area of circle is:"+(22/7)*(rad*rad));
                  break;
        case 'r': System.out.println("Enter length");
                  String l = br.readLine();
                  int len = Integer.parseInt(l);

                  System.out.println("Enter breadth");
                  String bd = br.readLine();
                  int breadth = Integer.parseInt(bd);
                  System.out.println("area of rectangle is: "+len*breadth);
                  break;
        case 't': System.out.println("Enter base");
                  String b = br.readLine();
                  int bas = Integer.parseInt(b);

                  System.out.println("Enter height");
                  String h = br.readLine();
                  int htg = Integer.parseInt(h);
                  System.out.println("area of triangle is: "+(1/2)*bas*htg);
                  break;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work and throws java.lang.NumberFormatException.
Can someone help me correct it?
p.s I am not allowed to use exception handling so could you please try to help me without using that? 
Thanks

Comment: Use a `Scanner` which has useful methods to do what you want

Comment: You can use regex to make sure it is a number before parsing it...If it's not a valid number re-prompt the user for a valid number.

Comment: Print out the string you're trying to parse. I bet there's a newline or something in it, because `br.read()` doesn't consume the line.

Comment: 1. I strongly advise that you learn more about number operations in Java. To start with, execute this code `System.out.println(22/7)`.
2. Your formula for area of circle is wrong. Pi is an irrational number and it cannot be expressed as fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to make sure it's a number is simply this:

```
if(!string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").isEmpty())
```

This only continues if your string is a number, If you want to check for doubles, it's a bit harder, but i'ts doable, here's a snippet of code for explanation of how.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,}\\.[0-9]{1,}?");
```

This is the pattern you need to check for, for a "double" format, it's basically saying any number 0-9 1 or more times then a dot then more numbers 0-9 1 or more times, which is what a double is.

Hope this helped you get your answer on how to do that, also, for the double checker you can use pattern.matcher(string).matches() to return if it's a double or not

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are starting off programming, I will suggest the following approach.

You should parse the input and verify that its a number.
Break the input into character array
Check if each char is a number ( between '1' to '0', or a . or a space)

This is one simple way of avoiding exception. If input is valid, process it, if its not, display an output, invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how you are capturing user input. Basically, when you created the input stream reader and called the `read` method it prompts for user input. But, when you call `readLine()` later it is still operating on the same first line (the character and a return). That is why you get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

You can fix your code by having it finish "consuming" the first line of input after reading the character:

```
char a = (char) br.read();
br.readLine(); // this finishes consuming the first line of input
```

Instead of using an input stream, consider using the Scanner class which is made for this type of purpose.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter c for circle,r for rectangle and t for triangle");
    String input = in.next();
    if (!input.isEmpty()) {
        char a = input.charAt(0);
        switch (a) {
            case 'c':
                System.out.println("Enter radius (int)");
                int rad = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("area of circle is: " + (22 / 7) * (rad * rad));
                break;
            case 'r':
                System.out.println("Enter length (int)");
                int len = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter breadth (int)");
                int breadth = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("area of rectangle is: " + len * breadth);
                break;
            case 't':
                System.out.println("Enter base (int)");
                int bas = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter height (int)");
                int htg = in.nextInt();
                // Note change to calculation
                System.out.println("area of triangle is: " + bas * htg / 2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

FYI one final thing to note is that your triangle calculation is broken. Since you are working with integers here it is going to do int arithmethic. `(1/2)` will **always** be 0 so your area will always be 0. Do the multiplication first then divide by 2 if you want an int result. If you want it to calculate more accurately, have it convert to a double first. The same is true for the circle radius, but not quite as bad since `22/7` isn't going to round to 0.

Example of making them doubles:

```
(22.0 / 7) * rad * rad
```

Note the `.0` on 22. That will make the first section into a double result and a double times an int is also a double so you will get double precision instead of integer precision.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that my triangle equation was broken.

Comment: the only problem I have now is that when I add br.readLine(); after my char user input, the virtual machine gets stuck and is not able to run the program in the terminal.

Comment: @UrvishRamaiya that's odd. It worked for me on my machine. I'd recommend trying to use the Scanner version instead.

Comment: ok, never mind the previos comment, I reset the virtual machine and works fine now. Thanks for your help!